# What is the difference between the function in assemble code which returns value and one which doesn't reutn value?

Tags: arm

Platform： Cortex-M3

IDE: Keil uVision5.10

Hello everyone ~

Here is a simple example:
The function which doesn't return value(let's say function1) in C code:

```
void add_one(int n)
{
    int a = n+1;
}
```

Its assemble code is:

```
ADDS   r1,r0,#1
BX     lr
```

The function  which returns value(let's say function2) in C code:

```
int add_one(int n)
{
    int a = n+1;
    return a;
}
```

and its assemble code is:

```
MOV     r1,r0
ADDS    r0,r1,#1
BX      lr
```

As far as I can see, the only difference is that function2 moves  parameter n from r0 and then excutes computation while function1 computes directly.
My confusion is that the two function both ends with

```
BX      lr
```

I know the the effect of the code is to make program jump to another adress which contained in register lr. How can function2 return value? What happened exactly?

Comment: Your observation about the role of `r0` is correct. The calling function will expect the return value in `r0` (if the return value is a register-sized integer or pointer), and will ignore the value in `r0` if the called function does not return anything (`void`).

Comment: If you're not familiar, the key concept here is "[calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)".

Comment: If you turned on optimization, the functions would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The return value is stored in `R0`. `BX LR` will jump back to the caller, which knows the function returns something and can now get it from the `R0` register. This agreement between caller and callee is named "calling convention".

You should check out the [Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf). For example, under 5.4 Result Return, it says:

> A word-sized Fundamental Data Type (e.g., int, float) is returned in r0.

Which is exactly what you're seeing.